# Android RadioButton *with* icon and center aligned

Tags: android, android-radiobutton, android-radiogroup, center-align

Is it possible to create a horizontal RadioGroup, with RadioButtons where each button includes a radio, icon, and text, and **these three items are vertically-center-aligned with each other**?

I have tried to set the `gravity` and `layout_gravity` on the `RadioGroup` and the `RadioButtons`, as well as the `layout_weight` on each button, etc, to no avail.  WHYYY is this so difficult on Android?

[image]

^ I want the radio buttons centered with the icons and titles.

I need the entire area to be selectable, so **I'd really like to set the RadioButton's icon and text values**, rather than add separate ImageViews the UI.  I want to use RadioGroup because I am using this in a custom `Preference` item, so the selection and persistence are handled nicely for me.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
    style="@style/AppTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:context=".settings.homeScreenPreference">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:text="@string/set_home_screen" />

    <!--Settings icon-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/settingsIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/settings_icon_description"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/settingsTitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/diidsIcon"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings" />

    <!--Cards icon-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/diidsIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/my_cards_icon_description"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_my_cards"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/home_screen_radio_group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scannerIcon"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/settingsIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_my_cards" />

    <!--Scanner icon-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/scannerIcon"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/scanner_icon_description"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_scan_qr"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/home_screen_radio_group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/diidsIcon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_scan_qr" />

    <!--Settings title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/settingsTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/home_screen_radio_group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/diidsTitle"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/settingsIcon" />

    <!--Cards title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diidsTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_cards"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/home_screen_radio_group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/scannerTitle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/settingsTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/diidsIcon" />

    <!--Scanner title-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scannerTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scan_code"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/home_screen_radio_group"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/diidsTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scannerIcon" />

    <!--Radio group-->
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/settingsTitle">

        <!--Settings radio-->
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <!--Cards radio-->
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/diidsButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent" />

        <!--Scanner radio-->
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/scannerButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorAccent"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use CheckedTextView Instead of RadioButton**
**And You will get this**

[image]

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_state"
    android:text="Settings"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/two"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_state"
    android:text="My DIID"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/three"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/one"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/three"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_state"
    android:text="Scan Code"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/two"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Make 2 drawable and add like this Now Background Drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" 
   android:state_checked="false" />

   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp" 
   android:state_checked="true" 
/>
</selector>
```

**Now MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckedTextView one,two,three;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    one = findViewById(R.id.one);
    two = findViewById(R.id.two);
    three = findViewById(R.id.three);
    mDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (one.isChecked()){
                one.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                one.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                one.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                one.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
    two.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (two.isChecked()){
                two.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                two.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                two.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                two.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
    three.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (three.isChecked()){
                three.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                three.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                three.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                three.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I see you left two detailed answers for me, and I'm testing them.  I need to be able to customize the size of the icon and I haven't figured out how to do that yet.  This is why I haven't selected either of your answers as the correct solution yet.  I'd really like to keep as much code styling in the XML as possible so as to keep the .kt code to a minimum.

Comment: Not a problem if you like it use it, if there is anything I can do more ask me.

Comment: It would be great if you could answer this other issue I have... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834600/preference-custom-subclass-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

**You want RadioButton in the center and text above like this**

[image]

**Here is the XML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:checked="true"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_state"
        android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text on top" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_state"
        android:drawableBottom="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Text on top" />
  </RadioGroup>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And Use 2 background drawable for state checked and unchecked**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" 
android:state_checked="false" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_android_green_24dp" android:state_checked="true" 
/>
```