# Custom Preference Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I'd like to subclass `Preference` to create a custom preference item in Kotlin.  I am unable to get the custom preference to inflate in the Preference screen.  If I remove this custom preference from my preference screen, the rest of the preferences I have implemented (not shown here) are working fine.  **There are many similar *seeming* questions here, but none of the ones I've found directly deal with the issue of creating a Kotlin implementation of a custom preference.**

Please help me with a working example **that you've tested** that shows three things:

1. `custom_preference.xml`
2. `CustomPreference.kt`
3. `preference_screen.xml` (Parent Preference screen to display custom preference)

Here is my code:
A custom `xml` preference item that displays a string (let's keep it simple for the example, although my preference will end up having significantly more functionality)

**custom_preference.xml**

```
<Preference 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CustomPreference">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a custom preference" />
</Preference>
```

A class that extends `Preference` and includes the proper constructors.

**CustomPreference.kt**

```
package com.example.myApp

import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.example.myApp.R
import com.example.myApp.R.layout.custom_preference

class CustomPreference (context: Context,
                            attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                            defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.preferenceStyle,
                            defStyleRes: Int = defStyleAttr)
    : Preference(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder?) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
        layoutResource = custom_preference
    }
}
```

The custom preference declaration in the `PreferenceScreen`.

**preference_screen.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.example.CustomPreference
        app:key="custom_preference_key"
        app:title="This is a custom preference" />
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Note: I manually renamed class names here for the example.  Also, I **must** use the support libs instead of Androidx for this project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set your layout resource in initialization of class, instead of `onBindViewHolder`. Also you should create the layout using normal widget elements (not `Preference`).

**CustomPreference.kt**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference
import android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceViewHolder
import android.util.AttributeSet
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.custom_preference_layout.view.*

class CustomPreference @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : Preference(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    init {
        widgetLayoutResource = R.layout.custom_preference_layout
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PreferenceViewHolder) {
        super.onBindViewHolder(holder)
        with(holder.itemView) {
            // do the view initialization here...

            textView.text = "Another Text"
        }
    }

}
```

**res/layout/custom_preference_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="This is a custom preference" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**preference_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.example.CustomPreference
        app:key="custom_preference_key"
        app:title="This is a custom preference" />

</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: @jungledev: Have you tested it?

Comment: yes and it j.u.s.t. worked.  Thank you for the concise and quality answer.  =)

Comment: Hello mate , i m also facing the same issue and i implemented it this way but in my fragment that extends fragmentPreferencecompat i m getting this error , do you know why android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class taki.food.foodappv.RatingPreferences

Comment: @takieddine: Do you use `androidx` in your project? However, I must see your code.

Comment: This is the whole code my friend on paste bin https://pastebin.com/9GdU7pS3 , thank you