# How can you make a Preference Screen that looks like this?

Tags: android, preferences

[image: Settings page]

Where do I get this style of Preference Screen? I'm specifically interested in creating the round rectangle shape around each list of preferences belonging to one preference category. I'm not sure if this is possible using the `android:layout` tag with a Preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `custom_background.xml` in your Drawable directory as follows:

**Right-click on Drawable directory** -> **New** -> **Drawable Resource File** -> **enter file name**(here it is custom_background) and **in root element select/enter "shape"**.

Now in your `custom_background.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#2196f3" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

You can also have attributes like padding, stroke etc in `custom_background.xml`
.

Now for each Preference, you can have a separate ConstraintLayout (or any other layout which you are using) under your main layout and then give `custom_background.xml` in the `background` attribute of that Preference layout as follows:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_preference_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_background">
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Give padding in `main_layout` according to your desired look.
Let me know if this solves your query.

Comment: Hi thanks this is a very thorough answer. The ConstraintLayout is confusing me though as it's not available in the `PreferenceScreen`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what layout you are using. You just have to give your custom_background.xml in the background attribute of your layout

Comment: I'm using a preference xml. I pasted it in this link: https://codeshare.io/Jbrm0n It's basically just generic preferences.

Comment: okay now I get it, you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53834600/custom-preference-android-kotlin

Comment: Hey. So I'm aware of this but I was wondering if there was a way to add the rounded rectangle background without having to create a whole new preference from scratch (since then I'd also have to manually add the values the default SharedPreferences file)